# Import email-ids from facebook account

Tags: facebook

I am new to Rails and want to integrate Facebook with my Rails application. 
I want to import email-ids of all my friends so that I can mail them a request to join my website.

I am using fb_graph API. I got app-key, secret key and canvas-url and configured my facebook.yml as follows:

```
client_id: 117950878254050
  client_secret: 939b5e2ef40b1e58cad08b4416f21337
  scope: user_about_me,friends_about_me,user_activities,friends_activities
```

But, I am totally lost after this. What to do next. Kindly suggest me the process to achieve my my goal.

Answer (score 1):

You are only allowed to get the email address of the current user, and not the entire friend list. You should use the Requests API to send invites to friends using the API instead.